Fulfillment Order Status Report with history
I need to generate a Salesforce Report with a history of Fulfillment Order Status for each Order Product in the Order. Here are the fields I need:
ORDER_NUMBER, PRIME_LINE_NUMBER, FULFILLMENT_ORDER, FULFILLMENT_ORDER_STATUS, STATUS_DATE, FULFILLMENT_ORDER_QUANTITY, FULFILLMENT_ORDER_REJECTED_QUANTITY

I am trying to build this Salesforce Report, but I am not seeing a way to get the history of the Fulfillment Order. All I am able to get is the current status of the Fulfillment Order.

This question is similar to: How to get the fulfillment status history in SF OMS. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@identigral this is a different question. I just need to create a Salesforce Report for Status history. The other question is related to extracting the Fulfillment Status history for use in Warehouse.

Out of the box, change of any field's value can be recorded via Field History Tracking (FHT). Unless the app (CPQ in this case) makes special provisions for it, FHT is the only way to get there. As far as we know, CPQ doesn't do anything special for this use case.

okay. how do I use that in a Salesforce Report?
